# Vaadin and js function

Tags: java, javascript, url, vaadin

I want to call js function by execute this string in vaadin code:

```
String js = "function returnURL{" +
                "return(window.location.href.replace(/(\\d+)$/, function(str, p1, p2) {" +
                    "return((Number(p1) + 1) + p2);" +
                "}));" +
            "}";
```

how to exacly call this function by this way :

```
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(javascript function);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a little error in your js code, You should have:

```
String js = "function returnURL(){" +  //Check the parens here
            "return(window.location.href.replace(/(\\d+)$/, function(str, p1, p2) {" +
                "return((Number(p1) + 1) + p2);" +
            "}));" +
        "}";
```

Then:

```
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(js);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers